# Login to Access Facebook data on my Server with FB PHP SDK and Cordova App

Tags: php, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I can't figure out the logic flow for a cordova app I am creating.  Here is what I want to do.

1. User is using a Cordova app I am creating and they login to Facebook with a plugin I have (wizcorp Cordova plugin).  Nothing in the login process communicates with my own server.
2. After login my server needs to access some data on my web server in a database that I may have previously saved about this user.  (Like posts they have made to their friends through the app).
3. I need to verify in some PHP code that the user is truly this fb user and not an imposter so I imagine I need to use the access token returned to the user in the app.
4. I can easily send the token to my PHP code but I can't figure out how to use the PHP Facebook SDK to set this token and get the verified user's Facebook ID.

Here is my PHP code.

```
    require_once("fb/autoload.php");

//Create the Facebook service
$facebook = new Facebook\Facebook ([
    'app_id' => '12345',
    'app_secret' => '67890',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4'
    ]);

$facebook->setAccessToken($_REQUEST['access_token']);

if (($userId = $facebook->getUser())) {
    echo "userId=$userId<br/>";
}
```

I am getting this error: Call to undefined method Facebook\Facebook::setAccessToken()

Comment: For anyone interested, I've solved the issue by using curl to call the graph API and passing the access token in the request.  Snipper below.

Answer (score 0):

```
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
 CURLOPT_URL => "https://graph.facebook.com/$fb_user_id?fields=id%2Cname&access_token=$access_token",
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
 CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
 CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
 CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
 CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
 CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
 CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
   "cache-control: no-cache",
   "postman-token: 3602fbe6-2faf-9c7f-05b0-bcaea8548000"
 ),
));
```